# Add button on the fly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I read the tutorial regarding creating buttons, it was pretty simple & straightforward.

However, I want to create buttons on the fly.  I have a status column.  It has a drop down menu created from a range of cells on a hidden sheet.  This is working code.

Here's the wish list.  When “status X” is selected, I want the button to appear.  The user can then push the button to increment a counter (which is displayed).  Track needs to be kept of the date & time (also displayed – including the history) when the button is pressed.  The previous button press date & time is always displayed.

Once the counter reaches some number – say 10, a warning message pops up which the user must acknowledge, and then the status automagically changes, button disappears and the entire row (with a color change) is moved to another page (or possibly another spreadsheet entirely).

Currently I have a function that simply changes the row color when the status changes, and also moves the row to another page.  I imagine the button would get created around that point somehow.  Other than what the tutorial says which I don't think really applies, I don't really know how to move forward.  Any help?

Please note for the record I find using the “active page” a bad idea in my case, as I have several pages where this might execute from.  So, I use “sourceSheet” and “targetSheet” for everything.

Thank you

//happyFunTime is installed as an edit trigger.

```
function happyFunTime() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();

    // set row color as soon as we know the status
    var i = r.getRow();

    var targetSheetName=setRowColor(i);


   // moveRow(targetSheetName);

  }

function setRowColor(i)
{

  var sName;
  var outCome = [];
  var color;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var statusColumnOffset = getStatusColumnOffset();
  var rowRange = range.offset(i-1, 0, 1);
  var status = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset).getValue();


outCome=checkStatus(status);

sName=outCome[0];
color=outCome[1];
rowRange.setBackgroundColor(color);    

return sName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing any code to achieve this programmatically? If you do, post it here, as its easier to gain a better understanding of your working code, and to build on it. Or do you just want someone to write te code for you?
All you have described is certainly possible to achieve programmatically, I suggest researching the onEdit trigger, as a means to an end.

Comment: Absolutely I have code.  I just don't think it's going to help.  As I mentioned, I don't know how to move forward from here.  Adding a button the way the tutorial teaches doesn't require code.... but then, their button is static.  Code added above.